# Using CSS selectors in HTML templates

Tags: html, css, template-engine

After accidentally using a CSS selector in an HTML template I started wondering if there is a template language or an extension to one that would allow this syntax, and whether it would be useful. So instead of writing this:

```
<div id="mydiv">
  <div class="first column">1</div>
  <div class="second column">2</div>
</div>
```

We could write it like:

```
<div#mydiv>
  <div.first.column>1</div>
  <div.second.column>2</div>
</div>
```

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Quite a cool idea. Will definitely help in unifying the selector syntax across HTML, CSS and jQuery etc.. Maybe you can build a custom HTML processor and link it up via an apache module (like we link up PHP to process .php files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you mean something like [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/)?

It is an HTML preprocessor.

The following:

```
doctype 5
html(lang="en")
  head
    title= pageTitle
    script(type='text/javascript')
      if (foo) {
         bar()
      }
  body
    h1 Jade - node template engine
    #container
      if youAreUsingJade
        p You are amazing
      else
        p Get on it!
```

Will be translated to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Jade</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if (foo) {
        bar()
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Jade - node template engine</h1>
    <div id="container">
      <p>You are amazing</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Also, it is not exactly what you're asking, but you may like [Zen Coding](https://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/). It is a plugin to code HTML at high-speed. GIF showing what it does:

[image: zen coding animated gif]

It's basically:

1. Write pseudo-html.
2. Hit the shortcut.
3. Get full HTML.
4. ?????
5. Profit!

You should check with your editor if it can support this. FWIW, I use [this](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2981) in VIM and it's awesome.

Comment: Thanks! Jade seems pretty cool especially for Python projects - although I adore Django's own templating system too much to make a switch at least for now.

Comment: @Kaivosukeltaja I edited to add zen coding to the answer. It may suit you for direct needs :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [haml](http://haml.info/) will fit your needs? It looks very similar.

Comment: +1 HAML is pretty much what the op is looking for only even more efficient than what he wrote.

Answer (score 2):

There's a tool that uses a similar (though not identical) syntax called [Zen Coding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/). You type this in your Zen Coding enabled editor:

```
div#page>div.logo+ul#navigation>li*5>a
```

... and get it expanded to:

```
<div id="page">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <ul id="navigation">
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
                <li><a href=""></a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

This differs from what you describe in that it doesn't require a preprocessor to run the template, it's just an editor helper to compose the final HTML. It may suit your needs or not.